# Return a value wrapped in Task<T>, what is the difference?

Tags: .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

Let's say I have a function return `Task<bool>`, basically I can implement it in 2 ways, what is the difference, pros/cons?

```
public async Task<bool> FooAsync()
{
    return await Task.Run(() => 
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        return true;
    });
}

public Task<bool> FooAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(() => 
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        return true;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is of asynchrony (code can move further after calling this, response will come) vs parallelism (parallel code execution)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's actually not necessary to return a `Task<bool>` in your first example since you already awaited it and got the result.

The difference between the two examples is that in your first case you actually await the given `Task` which will unwrap the result, which means you already have the boolean to work with.

The second example will actually return a `Task<bool>` which represents the ongoing work of returning a boolean and it basically says it will return a boolean in the future. Whoever uses your method is responsible to await in order to get the result wanted.